# "Override" properties of an imported Ant file

Tags: java, ant, properties

I´d like to override some properties of an imported Ant-File which handles most of the basic stuff to deploy an application. First of all I know that Properties in Ant are immutable. But I can think of two ways to "override" properties for my needs and I´d like to know, which one should be the prefered approach, and/or if there are any things to consider by doing it one way or the other.

Imagine we have following *master-build-script*, which I like to import in my build-script:

```
<project name="Application" default="build" basedir=".">

    <property name="overridden" value="false" />

    <target name="build">
        <echo message="Value of overridden is ${overridden}" /> 
    </target>
</project>
```

Now I want to override the *overridden* property. In both cases I import the *master-build-file*. I use import over include, because I also want to override some targets. I know of two possible solutions to override them:

1) Since Properties are immutable I can just define the properties I´d like to "override" by defining them before I actually import the master-file:

```
<project name="MyApplication" default="buildApplication" basedir=".">

    <property name="overridden" value="true" />

    <import file="master-build.xml" />

    <target name="buildApplication">
        <antcall target="build" />
    </target>
</project>
```

2) I define Params within the Ant call which seems to redefine a properties value as well:

```
<project name="MyApplication" default="buildApplication" basedir=".">

    <import file="master-build.xml" />

    <target name="buildApplication">
        <antcall target="build" >
            <param name="overridden" value="true"/>
        </antcall>
    </target>
</project>
```

In both cases the result is:

```
build:
     [echo] Value of overridden is true
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Would anyone be so kind and could explain me the difference and might also explain why I should use one way over the other, or even should use a different approach to get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between your first and second examples is that in the second case the property is only defined for the sub-build, which might sometimes be what you want, rather than globally for the build.

Other ways you can preemptively define properties globally...

**Pass as JVM args** when you execute ant, e.g.

`ant -Doverridden=true`

**Define the properties in a file** and load at start of your build, e.g.

build.properties:

```
overridden=true
```

build.xml:

```
<project name="MyApplication" default="buildApplication" basedir=".">

<property file="build.properties/>
```

A useful variant is to load user definable properties from the user home directory, e.g. something like:

```
<property file="${user.home}/MyApplication/build.properties/>
```

The advantage of both of these methods over the examples you gave are that the properties are overridden without changing the build file.

Answer (score 1):

Ant versions 1.8 and later come with the [`<local/>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html) task which allows you to declare a property as local. This might be what you need.

Another choice is to use [`<macrodef>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) which allows you to define your own macro (which is better than using `<antcall>` since `<antcall>` can break Ant's ability to create a execution matrix).

Comment: I honestly didn´t know about macrodef beeing prefered over antcall. That´s really intersting and I already found some articles dealing with the advantages of macrodef over antcall. Thanks for sharing that!